# Trying to write a iterative algorithm but can´t get it to work

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write an algorithm for calculating numbers in a number sequence, starting with `{ 0, 1, 2 }`, where additional numbers are calculated using the formula, `n = (n - 1) + (n - 3)`, resulting in the sequence: `{ 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 22, 32, 47, 69, 101 }`, etc., using an iterative algorithm.

This is what I have tried:

```java
public long calculate(long n) {
    if (n <= 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return (n - 1) + (n - 3);
    }
}
```

However, when I'm testing it, it doesn't seem to be fully correct. Do you have any ideas on what I can improve?

Comment: May be you want `f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 3)`? i.e. `return calculate(n-1) + calculate(n-3);`. Note, that `(n - 1) + (n - 3) == 2 * n - 4` and that's all

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to keep `3` values before `n`, so in general you have to keep all sequence before `n`. To do so, it's better to encapsulate it within separate class.

```java
public final class SequenceMaker {

    private final Map<Long, Long> cache = new HashMap<>();
    private long max = 2;

    {
        for (long n = 0; n <= 2; n++)
            cache.put(n, n);
    }

    public long calculate(long n) {
        if (n > max) {
            for (long i = max + 1; i <= n; i++)
                cache.put(i, cache.get(i - 1) + cache.get(i - 3));

            max = n;
        }
        
        return cache.get(n);
    }
}
```

And client code could look like this:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    SequenceMaker sequenceMaker = new SequenceMaker();

    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        System.out.print(sequenceMaker.calculate(i));
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

**Output:** `0 1 2 2 3 5 7 10 15 22 32 47 69 101`

**P.S.** *If you do not worry about performance, then you can avoid using caching.*

```java
public final class SequenceMaker {

    public long calculate(long n) {
        long[] cache = new long[4];

        for (long i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            cache[0] = i <= 2 ? i : cache[1] + cache[3];
            cache[1] = cache[2];
            cache[2] = cache[3];
            cache[3] = cache[0];
        }

        return cache[3];
    }
}
```

Or using `Deque`:

```java
public final class SequenceMaker {

    public long calculate(long n) {
        Deque<Long> queue = new ArrayDeque<>(3);

        for (long i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            queue.addFirst(queue.size() < 3 ? i
                                            : queue.removeLast() + queue.getFirst());

        return queue.element();
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to keep all the sequences before `n`, just keeping last three in the sequence is enough.

Comment: For sequence call this is correct. But what if the client call smth. `calculate(10)` and then `calculate(20)`?

Comment: I understand you are utilizing the existing discovered numbers of this sequence for the future one. It will be helpful if the task is stateful. For the stateless one, we have to optimize the memory.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is you did not make the recursive call for `(n - 1)` and `(n - 3)`. The following code have fixed the issue:

```
public long calculate(long n) {
    if (n <= 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return calculate(n - 1) + calculate(n - 3);
    }
}
```

The problem you have described here, is very similar to `Fibonacci Number`. [Here](https://dev.to/khalilsaboor/fibonacci-recursion-vs-iteration--474l) you will get an article on how to calculate `Fibonacci Number` by using both recursive and iterative way. Here is the corresponding iterative algorithm of your problem:

```
public class Calculate{
    
    public static long calculate(long n) {
        if(n < 3) return n;
        
        int [] cache = new int [3];
        int tmp;
        cache[0] = 0;
        cache[1] = 1;
        cache[2] = 2;
        
        for(int i=3; i<=n; i+=1) {
            tmp = cache[2] + cache[0];
            cache[0] = cache[1];
            cache[1] = cache[2];
            cache[2] = tmp;
        }
        return cache[2];
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        for(int i=0; i<20; i+=1) {
            System.out.print(" " + calculate(i));
        }
        System.out.println("");
     }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
 0 1 2 2 3 5 7 10 15 22 32 47 69 101 148 217 318 466 683 1001
```

Here you can see, I have only cached last three elements in this series. This is because to calculate `n-th` entry of this series, we only need to need `(n-1)-th` and `(n-3)-th` entry of this series. So, the `cache` array in this solution acts as a sliding window. If memory is not an issue, you can keep an array of size `(n+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is recognizing that the sums are sums of `nth` and `nth+2nd` elements.  So you can do it like this without recursion.  But you need to keep track of two earlier elements to do it.

```
int a = -1;
int b = -0;
int c = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    int v = fnc(a, c);
    a = b;
    b = c;
    c = v;
    System.out.println(v + " ");
}
```

Prints

```
0 1 2 2 3 5 7 10 15 22 32 47 69 101
```

The method which just adds the appropriate elements

```
public static int fnc(int a, int c) {
    if (c < 2) {
        return a + 1;
    }
    return a + c;
}
```

In fact, you don't need a method at all, just do it like this using the earlier values for `a`,`b`, and `c`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    int v = a + c;
    if (c < 2) {
        v = a + 1;
    }
    
    a = b;
    b = c;
    c = v;
    
    System.out.print(v + " ");
}
```